How to save FCM Token automatically to Firebase Cloud Messaging
I am using firebase cloud messaging server to send notification to all users but I have to put the FCM token to firebase cloud messaging manually . My question is how to add the token automatically. Here is my code to get the token in my app


Where is your code and where you want save FCM token? Please clarify.

thank you for your help , i will save them in firestore ,,, but still send a notification for  every token manually ,,, How do I send them all at once?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
